# Swift Structure Extension Providing Get Only Data, and I can't Change the Data

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've got a swift structure that looks like this

```
struct WidgetView: Identifiable, Hashable{
    static func == (lhs: WidgetView, rhs: WidgetView) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.friendlyName == rhs.friendlyName && lhs.order == rhs.order && lhs.selected == rhs.selected
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    var friendlyName: String
    var view: Any
    var order: Int
    var selected: Bool = false

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}

extension WidgetView {
    static var data: [WidgetView] {
        [
            WidgetView(friendlyName: "News", view: MusicView(), order: 1),
            WidgetView(friendlyName: "Music", view: MusicView(), order: 2),
            WidgetView(friendlyName: "Ambiance", view: AmbianceView(), order: 3),
            WidgetView(friendlyName: "Weather", view: WeatherView(), order: 4),
            WidgetView(friendlyName: "Routines", view: MusicView(), order: 5)
        ]
    }
}
```

And I've been trying to edit the WidgetView Extension Data through two functions that look like this:

```
func resetSelected() {
    for i in 0..<WidgetView.data.count {
        WidgetView.data[i].selected = false
    }
}

func onSelectedLoad() {
    var widgets = [WidgetView]()
    var ambianceWidget = widgets.firstIndex(where: { $0.friendlyName == "Ambiance"})
    WidgetView.data[ambianceWidget!].selected = false
    
}
```

However, both functions have the same

> Cannot assign to property: 'data' is a get-only property

And I want to be able to change the data that is in the extension, specifically the "Selected", and "Order" parts. I've been looking around and I can't seem to understand why my code is coming up as "Get Only." Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
extension WidgetView {
    static var data: [WidgetView] =   // <--- here
        [
            WidgetView(friendlyName: "News", view: MusicView(), order: 1),
            WidgetView(friendlyName: "Music", view: MusicView(), order: 2),
            WidgetView(friendlyName: "Ambiance", view: AmbianceView(), order: 3),
            WidgetView(friendlyName: "Weather", view: WeatherView(), order: 4),
            WidgetView(friendlyName: "Routines", view: MusicView(), order: 5)
        ]

}
```

Note, although "onSelectedLoad" does not make sense, you should avoid using "!", use this instead:

```
func onSelectedLoad() {
    let widgets = [WidgetView]()  // an empty array
    // try to find something in an empty array ???
    let ambianceWidget = widgets.firstIndex(where: { $0.friendlyName == "Ambiance"})
    if let ambianceWidget = ambianceWidget {
        WidgetView.data[ambianceWidget].selected = false
    }
}
```